# How to call Tk functions from OCaml (that lablTk does not have)?

Tags: ocaml, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use lablTk to build a GUI in an OCaml application under Linux. I would like to select a directory; Tk has a function called `chooseDirectory` for this, but lablTk does not have this function. How can I select a directory from a standard dialog? Tk 8.4 supports this functionality, and I expected that OCaml can use it.

Actually, there is very little documentation directly on the Tk module of lablTk. I see from [this documentation](http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godipkg/3.11/godi-ocaml-labltk/lib/ocaml/std-lib/labltk/tk.cmi_pretty) that there are functions such as `getOpenFile` and `getSaveFile` in the Tk module, but not `chooseDirectory`.

1. How can I see the functions exported by lablTk in the Tk module? There is no tk.mli file in /usr/lib/ocaml/labltk/. Does it mean that the C side of the Tk module directly binds to functions such as `getOpenFile`, without going through an OCaml module?
2. If the Tk module can bind these functions directly, maybe I can do a little work and directly call a Tk function not included in lablTk, such as `chooseDirectory`? Is it possible to call this function by declaring it as "external" in some way (how?), or do I need to do more work? I would consider writing a little wrapper in C so that I can call more Tk functions in addition to the functions available in lablTk, if this were possible and not very time consuming; or do I have to modify the sources of lablTk, recompile and install a custom version of lablTk, just so that I can use a few more Tk functions? If so, how do I recompile lablTk with these changes, and what should I keep in mind? (Where can I see the documentation?)

Comment: Many functions of labltk are auto generated by a description file Widget.src. If you want to add new tk functionality, edit that file and regenerate functions. If you feel it is too heavy, you can also use tkCommand function to send raw tk commands from OCaml.

Comment: The idea of using `tkCommand` is interesting, and I will explore it, but now I see another problem with this approach. How can I execute `chooseDirectory` as a raw Tk command? This command should show a dialog box and return a string to my program. How can I get this string, if `tkCommand` has type `Protocol.tkArgs list -> unit`, that is, `tkCommand` cannot return any string value?

Comment: I looked again in the Protocol module and guessed that in this case, `tkEval` should be used instead of `tkCommand`. Sample code: `Protocol.tkEval (Array.of_list [Protocol.TkToken "tk_chooseDirectory"; Protocol.TkToken "-title"; Protocol.TkToken "choose dir..."])`